# Proxy server using socks5

Tags: c++

I have a problem when i`m sending my last packet,as I said in the comentary,I'm getting an warning sayng that i returned an unexpected answer follow by a different hex number every time i run it.
I am using Proxifier to test this,it always give me this when i try to connect to google:

`[06:22] Starting: Test 1: Connection to the Proxy Server

[06:22] IP Address: 127.0.0.1

[06:22] Connection established

[06:22] Test passed.

[06:22] Starting: Test 2: Connection through the Proxy Server

[06:22] Authentication was successful.

[06:22] Warning : the proxy server has returned an unexpected answer (0x32).

[06:22] Connection to www.google.com:80 established through the proxy server.`

```
`void HandleConnection()
{
    cout << "You are connected !!!" << endl;
    char temp[30];
    Recv(temp, sizeof(temp));
    if(temp[0] == 5) // test for version
    {
        cout << "Version good" << endl;
        char* reply = new char[2];
        reply[0] = 5; // version
        reply[1] = 0; // method choosed (no auth required)
        Send(reply, sizeof(reply));
        delete [] reply;
        memset(temp, '\0', sizeof(temp));
        Recv(temp, sizeof(temp));
        temp[sizeof(temp)] = '\0';
        if(temp[0] == 5) // test for version
        {
            if(temp[4] == 14) // test for lenght of www.google.com
            {
                char* domain = new char[temp[4]];
                for(int i = 0; i < temp[4]; ++i)
                {
                    domain[i] = temp[i + 5]; // copy domain name
                }
                domain[14] = '\0';
                cout << endl;
                cout << domain << endl;
                int domainLen = strlen(domain);
                //with this packet i get a warning that i send an unexpected answer
                char* reply = new char[domainLen + 6]; 
                reply[0] = 5; // version
                reply[1] = 0; // succed
                reply[2] = 0; // reserved
                reply[3] = 3; // its a domain
                reply[4] = domainLen; // lenght of domain
                for(int j = 0; j < domainLen; ++j)
                {
                    reply[j + 5] = domain[j];
                }
                reply[4 + domainLen] = 80; // port
                Send(reply, domainLen);
                delete [] reply;
            }
        }
    }

}`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following those lines of code:

```
if(temp[4] == 14) // test for lenght of www.google.com
{
    char* domain = new char[temp[4]];
    //....
```

Maybe it should be

`domain[13] = '\0';` instead of `domain[14] = '\0';`

Comment: Also, C++ does not support C's Variable Length Arrays. But I guess you use `gcc` which offers such extension

Comment: no,if i use domain[13] = '\0' i get only the www.google.co part without the 'm'

Comment: @vBx You shouldn't use `domain[14]` . Try to increase the array size then.

Comment: i changed so domain would have lenght of 15,still having the same problem with that packet...

Comment: @vBx, I am looking. If I find something else I will let you know. BTW The same problem is here `temp[sizeof(temp)] = '\0';`

Comment: @vBx, try `Send(reply, domainLen+1);`

Comment: @vBx, try `Send(reply , sizeof(reply));`

Comment: still not working and it doesnt output the "Connection to www.google.com:80 established through the proxy server." part

Comment: @vBx, hm. Sorry my knowledge can only go this far. Maybe someone else will see your code and will propose, something. Make sure you fix all the out of bound array access though.

Comment: @Muggen: when i create replay i use domainLen + 6 and when i send i use just the domain lenght without +6, that was the problem :)

Comment: @vBx, ok good that you found the solution. Hope I helped. You should keep in mind what said about Array Bounds. Remember that when used with `char` and eg. You allocate `char Array[15]` you may only use `0->14` but use `Array[14] = '\0'`, therefore only `0->13`. Good luck and Have fun!